# Unable to locate package python-gnomedesktop: Installing PyViz in ns3

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, sudo, ns-3

I am following the commands [here](http://www.nsnam.com/2014/08/installing-pyviz-in-ns3.html) to install PyViz.

I get the error:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-gnome2-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-gnome2-desktop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python-wnck:i386 python-rsvg:i386 python-gnomekeyring:i386 python-wnck python-rsvg python-gnomekeyring

E: Package 'python-gnome2-desktop' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to search the solutions for the problem but all give the same error.

I have Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just python-gnome2:

```
python-gnome2
```

You can see with an *apt-cache search*:

```
$apt-cache search python-gnome2
    python-gnome2 - Python bindings for the GNOME desktop environment
    python-gnome2-desktop-dev - Python bindings for the GNOME desktop environment
    python-gnome2-dev - Python bindings for the GNOME desktop environment - development files
    python-gnome2-doc - Python bindings for the GNOME desktop environment
```

You actually need to install [`python-gnome2-desktop-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/python-gnome2-desktop-dev), `python-gnomedesktop` will be installed with the dev package.

```
python-gnomedesktop (>= 2.32.0+dfsg-1)
Python bindings for the GNOME desktop library
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now get: python-gnome2 is already the newest version.
python-gnome2 set to manually installed.

Comment: You need`python-gnome2-desktop-dev`, you can see in the link the packages that are included

Comment: `python-gnome2-desktop-dev` is now just called `python-gnome2-dev` and can be installed standalone with `apt install python-gnome2-dev` for GTK development.